# forward a single message from queue with sendmail

Tags: freebsd, sendmail

I have a message in the mail queue which has been deferred because the recipient box is full. The message isn't in my mailbox, just the queue. Is it possible to forward that message to a different address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Serverfault!

I'm not familiar with Sendmail on freebsd, but if this were a linux system you could do the following:

1) Run `mailq` or review logs to identify the QID of the message stuck in the queue (e.g. `dB9JDWt06111`).
2) Navigate to the queue directory (e.g. `/var/spool/mqueue/`) and edit `qf<QID>` for the message in question.
3) Identify the following lines:

`rRFC822; oldrecipient@olddomain.com`
`RPFD:<oldrecipient@olddomain.com>`

and change them to:

`rRFC822; newrecipient@newdomain.com`
`RPFD:<newrecipient@newdomain.com>`

4) Retry messages in the queue by typing `sendmail -q`.  If you have a lot of messages stuck in the queue and want to selectively just retransmit the one email, you can type `sendmail -qI<QID>` with the value mentioned before... or `sendmail -qS<Sender address/domain>`

Comment: Better late than never? ‍♂️ Enjoy your long deserved points man.